# what's the difference between Blob and Blobbuilder or Blobbuilder's issue on android native browser

Tags: javascript, blob, android-browser

**The question is not duplicate from [What's the difference between BlobBuilder and the new Blob constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412299/whats-the-difference-between-blobbuilder-and-the-new-blob-constructor)**

I'm doing web app. To upload image I use `Blob`, just in case `BlobBuilder` too. `Blob` works well, but `Blob` doesn't work on *android native browser*, android native browser uses `BlobBuilder`. I expected, `Blob` and `BlobBuilder` returns the same blob, but they didn't. Here is my code:

```
base64toBlob: function(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
  var BlobBuilder, blob, byteArray, byteCharacters, byteNumbers, charCodeFromCharacter, err, posIndex;

  if (contentType == null) {
    contentType = '';
  }
  if (sliceSize == null) {
    sliceSize = 1024;
  }
  posIndex = b64Data.indexOf('base64,');
  if (posIndex !== -1) {
    b64Data = b64Data.substring(posIndex + 7);
  }
  charCodeFromCharacter = function(c) {
    return c.charCodeAt(0);
  };
  byteCharacters = atob(b64Data.replace(/\s/g, ''));
  byteNumbers = Array.prototype.map.call(byteCharacters, charCodeFromCharacter);
  byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  try {
    blob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], {
      type: contentType
    });
    return blob;
  } catch (_error) {
    err = _error;
    BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
    blob = new BlobBuilder();
    blob.append(byteArray.buffer);
    return blob.getBlob(contentType);
  }
}
```

I did logs when I send request

```
blobImg = base64toBlob(base64Data, imageType);
alert(JSON.stringify(blobImg));
// alert shows {"type": "image/jpeg", "size": 10251 } when blob worked
// alert shows {"type": "image/jpeg", "size": 27822 } when blobbuilder worked
ajaxRequest.send(blobImg);
```

I tried to upload at the same image on all browsers. On Chrome and other browsers  I get from log `{"type": "image/jpeg", "size": 10251 }` and request send successfully, but on android native browser i get `{"type": "image/jpeg", "size": 27822 }` and request failed with status code `0`. On android browser works `catch` part (I guess, it means Android native browser does not support Blob) I tested in **android 4.1.2**. I found nothing from  google about the issue. I will glad If somebody help me!

Comment: I have same issue.Do you have any idea how to solve this?A workaround is also acceptable.Appreciated in advanced.

Comment: @ablian, I created an answer

Answer (score 4):

Note the difference between what you pass in:

```
try {
    blob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], { // use of .buffer
      type: contentType
    });
    return blob;
} catch (_error) {
    err = _error;
    BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
    blob = new BlobBuilder();
    blob.append(byteArray); // just uses the raw array
    return blob.getBlob(contentType);
}
```

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder#append%28%29) for `BlobBuilder.append`:

> Appends the contents of the specified JavaScript object to the `Blob`
>   being built. If the value you specify isn't a `Blob`, `ArrayBuffer`, or
>   `String`, the value is coerced to a string before being appended to the
>   blob.

`byteArray` is not of type `ArrayBuffer`, so it's probably being coerced to a string. You can confirm this yourself by converting it to a string and checking its length. To fix it, just use `byteArray.buffer` in your `catch` block.

Interestingly enough, the [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Constructor)  appears to accept an `ArrayBufferView` directly, which your `Uint8Array` qualifies as. This may mean you don't actually need the `.buffer` in that case, though I'm not familiar enough with the API to say with any confidence.

Comment: Well, that invalidates my entire answer. Please take care and **never, ever paraphrase code** when asking questions. Providing an answer to a less common question like this one can take a significant time investment, and it's very discouraging to have that effort wasted because the code in the question isn't actually the code that presented an error. Always copy the code directly from the source and run the excerpt if possible.

Answer (score 2):

It works in our case, I don't know, does it work for you.

```
base64toBlob: (b64Data, contentType = '', needArrBuffer) ->
    posIndex = b64Data.indexOf 'base64,'
    if posIndex isnt -1
        b64Data = b64Data.substring posIndex + 7

    charCodeFromCharacter = ( c ) ->
        c.charCodeAt( 0 )

    byteCharacters = b64Data
    b64Data = b64Data.replace(/\s/g, '')
    try
        byteCharacters = atob?(b64Data)
        byteCharacters ?= Base64.decode(b64Data)
    catch err

    byteNumbers = Array.prototype.map.call(byteCharacters,
            charCodeFromCharacter)
    byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers)

    try
        new Blob [byteArray.buffer], type: contentType
    catch err
        if needArrBuffer
            # Android browser cannot send Blob by XHR, so we use ArrayBuffer instead of Blob
            return byteArray.buffer
        Util.log 'Warning: No native Blob supported! ' + err.message
        BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder
        blob = new BlobBuilder()
        blob.append(byteArray.buffer)
        blob.getBlob(contentType)


blobImg = base64toBlob(base64Data, imageType, true);
ajaxRequest.send(blobImg);
```